# Databinding in XAML so it works in the Designer-view?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, xaml

I'm having trouble understanding how to databind my Songs `List<>` to a `ListBox` without needing to set the `ItemsSource` in the code behind.
It works though, but I would really like to see the List working in the liveview Designer.

```
namespace App5
{
    class SongsData
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Lyrics { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And in my MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            List Songs = new List();
            Songs.Add(new SongsData() { Title = "Your Song", Lyrics = "It's a little bit funny.." });
            Songs.Add(new SongsData() { Title = "Rocket Man", Lyrics = "I'm the Rocket Maaaan.." });

            SongsListBox.ItemsSource = Songs;
        }
```

And in the XAML I have a basic ListBox:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Can a friendly person please help me understand what to change - and hopefully why - to get the songs title to show in the `ListBox` in the liveview Designer of Visual Studio?

With the above I have to Debug the program to see the song titles in the `ListBox`.

Many thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically need to apply the **DesignData** build time action to your data files. A very comprehensive walkthrough can be found at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602279(v=vs.95).aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much. I must be very stupid cause I don't understand the Walkthrough. Is it every step I have to do? 
I don't wanna declare the data (songs title, lyrics etc) in XAML but in the codebehind.

Comment: Dont get bugged down :) The declaration of data will still remain in code behind. You will just need to update the xaml to add the necessary databindings to control properties. The walkthrough explains very nicely how to go about doing this

Comment: Ok so what I might end up seeing in the Designer is not actually the data that I declare in the code-behind but just a sample I make? Is this correct understood?

Answer (score 1):

A quick and simple solution is to move your `ListBox` to a new `UserControl`, put the list initialization in the `UserControl`'s constructor, and then add an instance of the `UserControl` to your main form.

Example:

SongListControl.cs :

```
namespace App5
{
    public parital class SongListControl : userControl
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        List Songs = new List();
        Songs.Add(new SongsData() { Title = "Your Song", Lyrics = "It's a little bit funny.." });
        Songs.Add(new SongsData() { Title = "Rocket Man", Lyrics = "I'm the Rocket Maaaan.." });

        SongsListBox.ItemsSource = Songs;
    }
}
```

SongListControl.xaml :

```
<UserControl x:Class="App5.SongListControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>        
    </ListBox>
</UserControl>
```

Then in your main window :

```
<Window x:Class="App5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:app="clr-namespace:App5"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <app:SongListControl />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When you build the project, the constructor initialization will occur in MainWindow preview.